# Zooming property to my Description page

Tags: android, android-listview, zooming

I've some items in my list-view. In that list-view, if any item, will be clicked means, that'll be redirected to another page and shows in scroll-view, because of contents of that item having lot.

So, i just preferred the scrollview for that. In that same time i need to use the zoom property for that. How can i done that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a best way that is `WebView` for that. I've also done this with my project. I just get the details from the clicked item of listview and, passed into one webview. And, after, i've used the zoom property for that webview.

-Make a one layout with webview and whatever you need something there.

-And, use following code for that,

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.SMALLER);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<p  align=\"justify\"><b> " + title+"</p></b><p align=\"justify\"><br>"+ desc + "</p>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

in this code, the title & desc are my string values which is coming from listview.

**HelloWebViewClient()**

```
public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
 view.loadUrl(url);
 return true;
 }
}
```

This will make your this as simple.

Comment: Shall, i see your project. If it's in market means, please, give me the link.

Comment: Yes, Can you come [Android People](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people) please

Comment: Your answer is working for me. Thanks and as per our conversation in [Android People](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people) I'll make your answer as accepted.